# How to add space between every characters using C

Tags: c

I want a space between every character of a string like I will give input `"HELLO"`

the result will be `"H E L L O"`

I need help in that

[Edit from comments]

I want it in a string

```
  for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
    printf("\n String is: %s", str[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }
```

Comment: Do you need to have it in a string, or just when you print it?

Comment: i want it in a string

Comment: please show what you have tried so far. Otherwise, the question will likely get closed.

Comment: Then allocate a string twice as long and copy, adding a char and a space each time through a loop.

Comment: for(i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++){
   printf("\n String is: %s",str[i]);
   printf(" ");
   }

Comment: i did something like this

Comment: First, the code belongs *in the question*, not here in a comment.  Second, if *output* is all the end-goal is here, your idea is ok, but the wrong function. The loop body should have been `{ fputc(str[i], stdout); fputc(' ',stdout); }` . That is likely *all* that was required. I would do this with a simple pointer and throw away the `strlen`, but that's another matter.

Comment: Unclear "I want it in a string" or do you want it printed out?  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorter, more general answer is that you need to bump characters back, and insert a ' ' in between them.  What have you done so far? Does it need to be in place?

One (perhaps not optimal, but easy to follow solution) would be making a larger array, copying in alternating letters, something like (not guaranteed to work verbatim)

```
char foo[N]; // assuming this has N characters and you want to add a space in between all of them.
char bar[2*N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    bar[2*i] = foo[i];
    if (i != N - 1)
        bar[2*i + 1] = ' ';
}
```

Of course, this new string is in bar, but functions as desired. At what point are you having issues?

Comment: Since the OP is asking about strings (probably zero terminated), it would be better to check for the terminating 0 in the for loop.

Comment: You're right, looking for the null terminator is in general a better idea. If we don't know the actual size of the string, looking for a null terminator is the best option. 

However, if we just happen to know the length of the string is N (which we'd need to know since the new array needs to be 2N), this method is fine. The example here also has another issue where it'd have a space after the last letter, but the aim is to show a solution, not write the code for him.

Comment: but is giving a garbage value at the end

Comment: If the code is spitting out garbage, the likely error is the null terminator is not set properly (which could be a mistake with my code, it's not guaranteed to work verbatim). To be clear, you need to set the value for the character after the last one to 0 or '\0'. [This link](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/2530/spr17/Notes/C/String/nullterm.html) might explain better:

Comment: Thanks Daniel and everyone

Comment: "need to set the value for the character after the last one to 0" yet this code does not form a _string_ as it does not certainly contain a final _null character_.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void add_spaces(char need_to_add[])
    {
        int len = strlen(need_to_add);
        char with_spaces[len*2];
        int space_index = 0;
        for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
        {
            with_spaces[space_index]=need_to_add[i];
            with_spaces[++space_index]=' ';
            space_index=space_index+1;
        }
        printf("%s\n", with_spaces);
    }
    int main() 
    {
        char * a = "aaa";
        add_spaces(a); // fraught with problems

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n", with_spaces);` fails as `with_spaces` lacks a null character.